# How to make 5 minute countdown using TimeOfDay

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, stock

Candlesticks on stock market charts are created every minute. I have created a count down timer to tell me how many seconds are left until next candlestick is to be created.

```
//logic for 1 min candlestick
const int MINUTE = 60;
int currentSecond = DateTime.UtcNow.Second;
int nextMin = MINUTE - currentSecond;
minuteLabel.Text = nextMin.ToString();
```

The chart can also display candlesticks every 5 minutes for a different perspective. So in this scenario a candlestick is created every 5 minutes. This is what I'm having trouble with. How do I create a count down timer to show me how much time is left until the next candlestick is to be created? This is what I have so far:

```
//inefficient logic for 5 min candlestick
int currentMinute = DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
int nextFiveMin;

if (currentMinute >= 0 && currentMinute < 5) {
     nextFiveMin = ((5 * MINUTE) - (currentMinute * MINUTE)) - currentSecond;
}
else if(currentMinute >= 5 && currentMinute < 10) {
     nextFiveMin = ((10 * MINUTE) - (currentMinute * MINUTE)) - currentSecond;
}
else if (currentMinute >= 10 && currentMinute < 15) {
     nextFiveMin = ((15 * MINUTE) - (currentMinute * MINUTE)) - currentSecond;
}
//etc all the way to currentMinute > 55

TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(nextFiveMin);
fiverLabel.Text = t.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Although this code works fine I think that there's probably a much easier way to implement this that I can't think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
int currentMinute = DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
int diffMinutes   = (currentMinute/5 +1) * 5;
int nextFiveMin   = ((diffMinutes * MINUTE) - (currentMinute * MINUTE)) - currentSecond;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // from the current time, strip the seconds, then add one minute:
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0)).AddMinutes(1);

    // keep adding minutes until it's a multiple of 5
    while (dt.Minute % 5 != 0)
    {
        dt = dt.AddMinutes(1);
    }

    // display how much time until the next five minute mark:
    TimeSpan t = dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now);  
    fiverLabel.Text = t.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```